# Blank values SQL server how to make it return like null or 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get some value to use like Null or 0  but when I run this SQL I got nothing. Can you edit it for me?
My SQL

```
SELECT ISNUll(AuditNumber,'test'), CASE AuditNumber WHEN ' ' THEN 'test' ELSE AuditNumber END
FROM [MATGEM2RPGROUP].[dbo].[TestNotes]
WHERE AuditNumber = (
    SELECT MAX(AuditNumber)
    FROM [MATGEM2RPGROUP].[dbo].[TestNotes]
    WHERE TestCode = (
        SELECT [TestCode] 
        FROM [MATGEM2RPGROUP].[dbo].[SampleTests]
        WHERE SampleCode='2210-0084-03' AND AuditFlag=0
    )
)
```

My results

[image: not null not blank what is that?]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: first: this is not how sql is supposed to be used. you should learn about how to join tables. second: if your query returns no data, it will return 0 rows instead of 1 row containing null. that’s how it is

Comment: Read about SQL aliases, you need to give an alias name to your columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this. One is to use an `OUTER APPLY` to look up at most one TestNotes record for the given SampleTests record.

`OUTER APPLY` works similar to a `LEFT JOIN`, but allows joining to a subquery having more complex conditions (like `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`) than can be expressed in the `ON` condition of a regular join.

Take a look at:

```
SELECT
    ISNUll(TN.AuditNumber,'test'),
    CASE TN.AuditNumber WHEN ' ' THEN 'test' ELSE TN.AuditNumber END
FROM [MATGEM2RPGROUP].[dbo].[SampleTests] ST
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 TN1.*
    FROM [MATGEM2RPGROUP].[dbo].[TestNotes] TN1
    WHERE TN1.TestCode = ST.TestCode
    ORDER BY TN1.AuditNumber DESC
) TN
WHERE ST.SampleCode='2210-0084-03'
AND ST.AuditFlag=0
```

If more than one matching TestNotes record is found, the one with the largest AuditNumber is returned. If no matching TestNotes record is found, that part of the query returns nulls, but the overall query still returns one row.

I'll haven't changed the SELECT expressions. Of the ones you originally posted, the first should handle the null/not-found case. I don't think the second one is going to work as you intended.